# What would be a better way to handle this sql logic?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Inside of a stored procedure, I populate a table of items (#Items). Just basic information about them. However for each item, I need to make sure I can sell them, and in order to do that I need to perform a whole lot of validation. In order to keep the stored procedure somewhat maintainable, I moved the logic into another stored procedure.

What would be the best way to call the stored procedure for each item in the temp table?

The way I have it now, I apply an identity column and then just do a while loop, executing the stored procedure for each row and inserting the validation result into a temporary table. (#Validation)

However now that logic has changed, and in between the creation of #Items and the execution of the loop, some records are deleted which screws up the while loop, since the Identity no longer equals the counter.

I could handle that by dropping the identity column and reapplying it before the while loop, but I was just wondering if there was a better way. Is there a way to get a specific row at an index if I apply an order by clause?

I know I could do a cursor, but those are a pain in the ass to me. Also performance is somewhat of a concern, would a fastforward readonly cursor be a better option than a while loop? The number of rows in the #Items table isn't that large, maybe 50 at most, but the stored procedure is going to be called quite frequently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Turn your validation stored procedure into a user defined function that accepts an item id or the data columns needed to validate an item record
2. Create the temp table
3. Insert all your items
4. Write a delete query for the temp table that calls your new UDF in the WHERE clause.

Comment: Thanks, this should work great. I'm not that familiar with user defined functions though, is this going to be costly performance wise?

Comment: No more so than looping through the items by hand.  Normally you could improve it by putting all the logic into the where clause, but that would be even harder to read/maintain and in this case wouldn't likely help much because your temp table probably doesn't have any indexes anyway.

Comment: user defined functions are very similar to sprocs, with some different limitations/functionality. Should perform OK (much better set-based than looping) and will benefit from having it's execution plan cached/reused.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that if you can do it set-based then do it that way. Perhaps put the validation into a user-defined function instead of a sproc to enable that. Which *may* pave the way for you to be able to do it set-based.

e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE dbo.fnIsValid(dataitem1, dataitem2....) = 1
```

However, I know this is may not be possible depending on your exact scenario, so...

**Correction edit based on now understanding the IDENTITY/loop issue:**
You can use ROW_NUMBER() in SQL 2005 to get the next row, doesn't matter if there are gaps in the IDENTITY field as this will assign a row number to each record ordered by what you tell it:
-- Gets next record
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY IDField ASC) AS RowNo, * 
FROM #temptable
) s
WHERE s.RowNo = @Counter

Comment: In the while loop, how would I select the row based on the @counter though? If I apply an order by, is there a way to access a row based on what is basically an index?

Comment: Ah I misunderstood. You can use ROW_NUMBER() instead to get each row in the loop, I will edit my answer to explain

Answer (score 1):

Does this kind of business logic really has to be in database?
I don't know much about your scenario, but maybe it would be best to move that decision you're trying to model with SPs into the application?

So you might try to use a function instead of stored procedure for that logic, and include the result of this function as a column in your temporary table? Would that work for you? Or if you need the data in realtime every time you use it later, then function returning 0/1 values, included in select list, could be a good bet anyway

Comment: Trust me, I'd much rather do this in code. However I don't have that option.

Answer (score 0):

If it's possible to rewrite your stored procedure logic using a query, i. e. a set-based approach?

You should try this first.

Comment: Are you referring to the validation stored procedure or the main stored procedure? Also I'm not sure how I could change this to a set based approach, aside from moving the massive amount of logic from the validation SP into the main one.